# Streams (aka "lazy lists") and tail recursion

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation

This question uses the following "lazy list" (aka "stream") type:

```
type 'a lazylist = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazylist)
```

My question is: how to define a *tail-recursive* function `lcycle` that takes a non-empty (and non-lazy) list `l` as argument, and returns the `lazylist` corresponding to repeatedly cycling over the elements `l`.  For example:

```
# ltake (lcycle [1; 2; 3]) 10;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1]
```

(`ltake` is a lazy analogue of `List::take`; I give one implementation at the end of this post.)

I have implemented several *non-tail-recursive* versions of `lcycles`, such as:

```
let lcycle l =
  let rec inner l' =
    match l' with
    | []   -> raise (Invalid_argument "lcycle: empty list")
    | [h]  -> Cons (h, fun () -> inner l)
    | h::t -> Cons (h, fun () -> inner t)
  in inner l
```

...but I have not managed to write a tail-recursive one.

Basically, I'm running into the problem that lazy evaluation is implemented by constructs of the form

```
Cons (a, fun () -> <lazylist>)
```

This means that all my recursive calls happen within such a construct, which is incompatible with tail recursion.

Assuming the `lazylist` type as defined above, is it possible to define a tail-recursive `lcycle`?  Or is this inherently impossible with OCaml?

EDIT: My motivation here is not to "fix" my implementation of `lcycle` by making it tail-recursive, but rather to find out whether it is *even possible* to implement a tail recursive version of `lcycle`, given the definition of `lazylist` above.  Therefore, pointing out that my `lcycle` is fine misses what I'm trying to get at.  I'm sorry I did not make this point sufficiently clear in my original post.

---

This implementation of `ltake`, as well as the definition of the `lazylist` type above, comes from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JJN_BAAAQBAJ&q=ltake#v=onepage&q&f=false):

```
let rec ltake (Cons (h, tf)) n =
  match n with
    0 -> []
  | _ -> h :: ltake (tf ()) (n - 1)
```

Comment: Will creation of a lazy_list ever involve the concept of being tail-recursive or not? basically your code is already "tail-recursive" if you insist. Basically, creation of a lazy_list will never stack overflow, but usage on a lazy_list can. Your `ltake` is not tail-recursive and you can make it tail-recursive.http://typeocaml.com/2014/11/09/magic-of-thunk-stream-list/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much of a problem with this definition. The call to `inner` is within a function which won't be invoked until `lcycle` has returned. Thus there is no stack safety issue.

Here's an alternative which moves the empty list test out of the lazy loop:

```
let lcycle = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "lcycle: empty"
  | x::xs ->
    let rec first = Cons (x, fun () -> inner xs)
    and inner = function
      | [] -> first
      | y::ys -> Cons (y, fun () -> inner ys) in
    first
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. `of_list` function will not take any stack space, and this is why lazy lists are so great. Let me try to explain the process. When you apply `of_list` function to a non empty list, it creates a `Cons` of the head of the list and a closure, that captures a reference to the tail of the list. Afterwards it momentary returns. Nothing more. So it takes only few words of memory, and none of them uses stack. One word contains `x` value, another contains a closure, that captures only a pointer to the `xs`.

So then, you deconstruct this pair, you got the value `x` that you can use right now, and function next, that is indeed the closure that, when invoked, will be applied to a list and if it is nonempty, will return another `Cons`. Note, that previous cons will be already destroyed to junk, so new memory won't be used.

If you do not believe, you can construct an `of_list` function that will never terminate (i.e., will cycle over the list), and print it with a iter function. It will run for ever, without taking any memory.

```
type 'a lazylist = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazylist)

let of_list lst =
  let rec loop = function
    | [] -> loop lst
    | x :: xs -> Cons (x, fun () -> loop xs) in
  loop lst

let rec iter (Cons (a, next)) f =
  f a;
  iter (next ()) f
```